# Create select field dynamically - >selected< option doesn't show up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm writing a function for dynamic creation of forms with jQuery.
Now I stuck at  due the selected parameter won't show up by any reason.
Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t2n2afc9/).

I don't assume this to be a big deal, however I got stuck.

```
// Creates select element with N options.
// options is an array with options
// name is the elements ID as a string
// selected, optionally, is the selected option. must be the same type as in options

function make_dynamic_select( options, name, selected ){
    select = "<select id='' type='' size ='1', name='" + name + "'>"    
    options.forEach(function(option){
        // a little debug
        console.log(typeof option,option," === ",typeof selected,selected,(option === selected))
        // append the option            
        select += (option === selected)? "<option selected>":"<option>" + option + "</option>"
    });
    return select += "</select>"
};
```

Comment: Use `select += (option === selected ? "<option selected>":"<option>" ) + option + "</option>"`

Comment: lol, even easier then assumed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not generating string correctly.

*Use*

```
select += (option === selected ? "<option selected>":"<option>" ) + option + "</option>";
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0g2wzerc/)

Comment: Gonna accept after cooldown.
Sometimes one does not see the wood for the trees. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/t2n2afc9/1/).

```
function make_dynamic_select( options, name, selected ){

    select = "<select id='' type='' size ='1', name='" + name + "'>"    
    options.forEach(function(option){
        console.log(typeof option,option," === ",typeof selected,selected,(option === selected))

        console.log(option === selected)

                select += (option === selected)? "<option selected>"+option+"</option>":"<option>" + option + "</option>"


    })
    select += "</select>"
    return select
};

$("#foo").append(make_dynamic_select([1,2,3],"bar",2));
```

Comment: Didn't downvote, but your solution is more code than needet, however, it works.

Comment: That is just a solution but someone downvoted that i didn't understand why